# Linear combination of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm supposed to say whether the following statement is true or false, with justification.

> If w is a linear combination of u and v in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then u is a linear combination of v and w.

In my textbook it says this is false, but I don't see how to reason that out.

In my mind, $w = c(u) + d(v)$, where c and d are constants. So we should be able to flip that around and say $u=\frac{1}{c}[w-d(v)]$.

What is the correct way to justify this problem?

EDIT: Okay, now I see the issue. Division by zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: The problem comes when $c=0$ and $u,v$ are linearly independent.